# Is declaring a new intger inside a loop changes the space complexity?

Tags: complexity-theory, space-complexity

Is declaring a new intger inside a loop changes the space complexity of the metohd?

for exampe if i'm looking at the follwoing 2 methods, is both of the methods space complexity is O(1)? or in the first method becuase I'm declaring the variable c over and over until the loop end it's space complexity is O(n)?

```
public static int what (int []a) {
    int temp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < a.length; j++) {
            **int c = f(a, i, j);**
            if (c % 2 == 0) {
                if (j - i + 1 > temp)
                    temp = j - i + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return temp;
}

public static int what (int []a) {
    int temp = 0;
    **int c;**
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < a.length; j++) {
            **c = f(a, i, j);**
            if (c % 2 == 0) {
                if (j - i + 1 > temp)
                    temp = j - i + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

```
Not sure if it's relevant to the question but also attahced the f method. 


private static int f (int[]a, int low, int high)
{
    int res = 0;
    for (int i=low; i<=high; i++)
        res += a[i];
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a variable inside the for loop it goes out of scope when the iteration ends and gets re declared in the next iteration so you are not declaring n variables, you are declaring a variable n times